# Android - Eclipse: Trace Files

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, sd-card, trace

I have two issues--but first thing's first:
Dell Inspiron M5030: AMD Athlon II P360
Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit SP 1
Android ADT 21.0.1-543035
org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.8.0-I20120608-1200
EMULATOR:
4.0" WVGA (480x800:hdpi)
Android 4.2 (API 17)
armeabi-v7a
RAM:512, VM Heap:16
Internal Storage: 600MB
SDCard Size 128MB, Use Host GPU

In the onCreate of my activity i have these lines:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.i(Constants.TAG_ACTSPLASH, "onCreate() Method called.");
        Debug.startMethodTracing("actsplash");
}
```

In the onDestroy of my activity i have these lines:

```
super.onDestroy();
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.i(Constants.TAG_ACTSPLASH, "onDestroy()");
            Debug.stopMethodTracing();
    }
```

PROBLEM NUMBER ONE: In debug mode, after onCreate is called, Logcat says:

```
davlikvm: Unable to open trace file '/mnt/sdcard/actsplash.trace': Permission denied
```

NOTE: when running the apk on my Epic4G (Android 4.2) the trace file is created.

PROBLEM NUMBER TWO: The tracefile extracted from the Epic4G can't be processed.
(1) When running traceview I get the error:

```
The standalone version of traceview is deprecated. Please use Android Device Monitor (tools/monitor) instead. trace file './actsplash.trace' not found
```

(2) When running ADM ('%SDK%/tools/monitor.bat') and loading the trace file i get:

```
Failed to read the stack trace.
```

This [article](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) says something about a key file...is that what's missing? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the 4.2 emulator; the 4.1 emulator processed the trace file and (unlike the 4.2 emulator) allowed me to pull the file and load it in ADM (Android Debug Monitor).

Answer (score 2):

The first problem can be fixed by adding the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to your app, so that it can write to /sdcard.  Alternatively, explicitly specify a filename for the trace file in your private app data storage area, and pull the file from there.

The second problem is "trace file not found", which is a direct result of the first.  The third problem appears to be a variation of the second.

The trace file itself used to be split into "key" and "data" files, but those were combined into a single .trace file a long time ago.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.
AndroidManifest.xml:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
as to using the private app data storage area, are you saying i can do this: "Debug.startMethodTracing("/data/data/<app-path>/actsplash.trace");"...? 
Let me also repeat that the trace file does appear on my phone when i run the program, but neither traceview nor ADM will process it.

Comment: Is there any way i can include the tracefile from my phone?

Comment: The permission looks right -- that should eliminate the "permission denied".  For the app data area, use `Context.getFilesDir()` rather than a hard-coded path, but you've got the right idea.  If you look at the trace file with a text editor you should see it start with `*version`, then some config info, then a list of methods following `*methods`, then after `*end` you'll find binary data.  Sometimes when things fail you get a zero-length file and not everything is good about telling you that, so check out the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

For problem number 2:
Traceview can't resolve relative paths. I had to specify the full path to the tracefile (still using only the basename) starting with "C:/"

http://www.talkandroid.com/android-forums/android-games-applications/509-traceview-cant-find-trace-file.html